# Создание и подключение модуля Angular

Tags: angular2, typescript, модули

Хочу создать модуль, который будет инкапсулировать следующие объекты:

```
// media.html-obj.ts
    import {JsonProperty} from 'json-typescript-mapper';

    export class Video {
        @JsonProperty('src')
        public src: string;
        @JsonProperty('type')
        public type: string;
        @JsonProperty('poster')
        public poster: string;
        @JsonProperty('preload')
        public preload: string;
    }

    export class Img {
        @JsonProperty('src')
        public src: string;
        @JsonProperty('alt')
        public alt: string;
        @JsonProperty('longdesc')
        public longdesc: string;
    }

// text.html-obj.ts
import {JsonProperty} from 'json-typescript-mapper';

export class Link {
    @JsonProperty('href')
    public href: string;
    @JsonProperty('ankor')
    public ankor: string;
    @JsonProperty('title')
    public title: string;
    @JsonProperty('target')
    public target: string;
    @JsonProperty('rel')
    public rel: string;
}

export class Button {
    @JsonProperty('name')
    public name: string;
    @JsonProperty('value')
    public value: string;
    @JsonProperty('type')
    public type: string;
    @JsonProperty('ankor')
    public ankor: string;
}
```

сам модуль:

```
// html-obj.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Video, Img } from '../html-obj/media.html-obj';
import { Link, Button } from '../html-obj/text.html-obj';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Video,
    Img,
    Link,
    Button
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    Video,
    Img,
    Link,
    Button
  ]
})
export class HtmlObjModule { }
```

И соответственно подключение этого модуля в корневой модуль приложения:

```
// app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HtmlObjModule } from '../app/html-obj/html-obj.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderSectionComponent } from './header-section/header-section.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { BodySectionComponent } from './body-section/body-section.component';
import { CtaBlockComponent } from './body-section/cta-block/cta-block.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderSectionComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    BodySectionComponent,
    CtaBlockComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HtmlObjModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

но консоль мне выдала следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пишет нужны обязательные директивы, порылся в поиске - есть много примеров как компоненты, сервисы и пр. заварачивать в модули, а вот просто объекты завернуть не нашел. Может кто подскажет что делать?

Comment: ну а зачем ты добавляешь свои модели в экспорты модуля? [exports](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#exports) > `модуль, который будет инкапсулировать следующие объекты` - нет такого понятия как инкапсуляция, есть понятие компиляция, для чего и существует модуль

Comment: @overthesanity хочу создать переносимый модуль с этими моделями, на будущее.. под инкапсуляцией я имел ввиду отделение от основного проекта

Comment: эти модели должны просто экспортироваться, но они не имеют отношения к `NgModule`, почитай документацию, у них отлично описано про разницу между обычным модулем и модулем в angular

Comment: @overthesanity получается это я уже перемудрил?

Comment: да, перемудрил. Забежал сильно вперед и начал делать свой велосипед :D